# Cmake uses wrong variable by default

Tags: macos, compilation, cmake, xcode5

Using CMake, a wrong variable is used by default for new builds.

`CMAKE_OSX_SYSROOT` is by default `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk`, but that directory does not exist (only `10.8.sdk`).

How do I set this variable to hold another default value?

Answer (score 0):

When configuring for the first time

```
cmake -DCMAKE_OSX_SYSROOT=/proper/path <path to source>
```

Comment: That works for that specific project. The default value for the next project is still the wrong one.

Comment: Then it's either a bug in CMake or intended way to work. Have you tried adding `set(CMAKE_OSX_SYSROOT "/proper/path")` in `CMakeLists.txt?

Comment: As long as there isn't a global CMakeLists.txt for the whole machine that won't help... The problem is not that I *can't* specify the variable for a single project, I can indeed, but the problem is that I *have to* specify it for every *new* project.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you have different version of OS X (macOS) SDK under:

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.12.sdk
```

and **version of OS X** system that **CLion** gets in `Darwin-initialize.cmake` by executing command:

```
execute_process(COMMAND sw_vers -productVersion
  OUTPUT_VARIABLE CURRENT_OSX_VERSION
  OUTPUT_STRIP_TRAILING_WHITESPACE)
```

You can try to execute this command in **Terminal**:

```
sw_vers -productVersion
```

I think that to set this globally it can be modified this file `Darwin-initialize.cmake` by setting new value of current macOSX SDK in this file